# Goutte Symfony DomCrawler Link

Tags: php, symfony, goutte

I'm scraping Buzzfeed for their articles and author names for an art project using Goutte.

```
public function postCreateArticle(Request $request) {
    $client = new Client();

    $listicleItems = array();

    $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://www.buzzfeed.com/crystalro/zoltar-speaks');

    for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        $listicle = $crawler->filter(".byline__author")->text();

        $listicleItems[] = $listicle;

        $link = $crawler->filter(".more_content_title")->link();
        $crawler = $client->click($link);
    }


    return $listicleItems;
}
```

It's failing when I filter for the .more_content_title nodes - I'm getting the "The current node list is empty." error. I would use selectLink(), but the text of this particular link changes every time the page is loaded. Not sure what's wrong.

Comment: If you "View Source" that page in a browser there's nothing called `.more_content_title` or `more_content_title`.

Comment: It's there for me, right below the comments. Maybe it's being loaded post page load?


<a href="/hilarywardle/reasons-americans-should-move-to-scotland-if-trump-is-electe" rel:gt_act="post/title" rel:buzz_id="4191443" rel:gt_label="editor/hilarywardle" class="more_content_title" data-bfa="@a:Title; @d:More-Stuff;"><span>19 Reasons Americans Should Move To Scotland, Not Canada, If Trump Is Elected</span></a>